# Safely remove Newtonsoft.Json reference from ASP.NET MVC4 Project

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, json.net

In my ASP.NET MVC4 Application, I don't need to use Web API.

All I  want is to use JsonResult in System.Web.Mvc. Is it safe to remove the package Newtonsoft.Json from my reference?

It seems to be added by default when creating an ASP.NET MVC4 application, so I am afraid removing it will cause problem to asp.net mvc framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core has a dependency on it. This package adds support to format and content negotiation to HTTP messages. It allows you to use Web APIs like:

```
http://example/api/attributes/?category=value
```

You can find more details [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you are including some google references in your bin folder:

```
Google.GData.Client.dll
Google.GData.Extensions.dll
Google.GData.Youtube.dll
```

this caused Newtonsoft.Json.dll to be added back into the project and bin folder during build.